# How could a beheaded Terminator search for its own head?

Tags: the-terminator, the-terminator-series

In the [second episode of season 1 of *The Sarah Connor Chronicle*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnothi_Seauton_%28Terminator%3a_The_Sarah_Connor_Chronicles%29), a Terminator named Cromartie reassembles himself:

> Another subplot is Cromartie's reassembling after he was supposedly destroyed in the previous episode by Sarah with an isotope-fueled weapon. His head falls out of the time displacement field and bounces on the grass. A highway worker finds it and keeps it for himself. Cromartie relocates his endo-skull and kills the highway man. He is later shown hiding among the homeless wearing a paintball mask.

So, supposing some other sensors compensate for the lack of eyes, how was his body able to search for his head if, as we saw in the [episode 5 of season 1](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_105%3a_Queen%27s_Gambit) , a Terminator could be deactivated by extracting the CPU from his head?

Comment: The head has auxiliary wireless communications to the body.

Comment: @GorchestopherH I think you nailed it down, could you put this as an answer?

Comment: Did you notice that the head went through the time displacement equipment without any living tissue?

Comment: Pre cursor to the T-1000. First the endoskeleton is able to find its own head and before long all pieces can find each other to join into one liquid body.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The head contains the CPU, so it follows that there should be some auxiliary wireless communication between the head and the body if the main communication lines were ruptured.

Comment: Must be some high bandwidth wireless tech there, that doesn't operate on any modern frequency.

Comment: It utilizes high enough technology to be in a Terminator movie.

Comment: The Iron Giant has better tech. All of it's parts meet in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

As another option, there might be a backup CPU in the torso. Heck, even dinosaurs had a brain in the torso.

Comment: Then, when the CPU is extracted from his head, the body should try to put it back!

Comment: ... Uh, source for "dinosaurs had a brain in the torso"?

Comment: @NominSim - apparently, this is currently being disputed - back when I was learning biology it was considered a fact. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stegosaurus#Second_brain

Comment: @DVK Apparently its no longer disputed among reputable paleontologists: http://blogs.smithsonianmag.com/dinosaur/2012/08/the-double-dinosaur-brain-myth/ (I was inspired to do some research into it.)

Answer (score 0):

It was actually a mimetic polyalloy terminator that did not want to blow its cover. Therefor when the two masses were separated, it continued the ruse until it was able to reunite the two parts of itself without giving away the secret that it is not, in fact, an endoskeleton model.

As evidence, I offer that there is no plausible way that its parts could communicate telemetry with wireless/radio... any signal powerful enough would have disrupted communications and the FCC would have found the head first. Additionally, it makes no sense that there would be backup CPUs in the torso of the robot. When all ordinary explanations have been ruled out, we must turn to the extraordinary.

Comment: This simply isn't the case.

Comment: @Valorum When all ordinary explanations have been ruled out, we must turn to the extraordinary.

Comment: So "*he was secretly a T-1000, despite the fact that that makes **absolutely no sense whatsoever***" is more sensible an explanation than "*he had a wireless transmitter in his head*"?

Comment: Who was he keeping the secret from?

Comment: @Valorum I suppose if you think RF is magic, your criticism is valid. I gave an honest answer though, using the best available information.